# Is there a way to install OpenSSL without installing man pages?

Tags: openssl

Unfortunately Perl somehow runs into errors when attempting to install man pages for OpenSSL (for example `OpenSSL_1_0_1g`). Because I don't need them - I want to use OpenSSL as C library only, I guess I could bypass this issue by skipping the installation of man pages altogether.

Comment: Well, I thought that question was already asked but I cannot find it. *＋1* for the originality.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes:

`make install_sw`

But, just to note, you should not be installing 1.0.1g at all. That is a very old, insecure and out of date version. Perhaps you meant 1.1.0g? There shouldn't be any perl errors during installation of an up to date OpenSSL. If you get them you can file a bug report here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues