# Is there a way to build openssl without docs?

Tags: openssl

I'm building an HTTP/3 version of curl per the instructions here:
https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/HTTP3.md

The build works fine as such, but the OpenSSL build installs docs which is actually a bit time consuming and produces pretty noisy output because it installs a lot of doc files. Is there a way to disable the building and installation of docs for OpenSSL?

Comment: Have you considered looking in the `makefile`?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136654/is-there-a-way-to-install-openssl-without-installing-man-pages

Comment: Oh, fantastic @MattCaswell. I searched pretty hard for a question like that, and none of the stackoverflow related questions pointed to the question nor your answer. I searched about not installing the "docs" and your answer is about installing "man pages" so it never came up. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

As @MattCaswell pointed out a the comment, the `install_sw` target avoids installing the man pages.

---

I searched for related questions and answers and this never came up, nor was it referenced as a related question via StackOverflow. Probably my question should be marked as a duplicate of:
[Is there a way to install OpenSSL without installing man pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47136654/629530)